# Divisors of $2^p+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We know the form of the divisors of $2^p-1$ where $p$ is prime.

Do we know anything about the form of the divisors of $2^p+1$ (except one of them is 3)?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the answer as simple as "3" (for $p>2$)?

Comment: We know the form of the divisors of $2^p-1$ where $p$ is prime??? On the contrary I believe.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question to state the obvious. The divisors of $2^p-1$ are in the form $(2ap+1)$

Comment: A prime divisor $q$ of $2^p+1$ divides $4^p-1$ so that if $q>3$, $q=2ap+1$.

Comment: @Aravind, $q=2ap+1$ can divide $2^p-1$.Can you show it divides  $2^p+1$

Comment: look for "Fermat's primes"

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, $p$ is a prime and $q>3$ is a prime-divisor of $2^p+1$.

Then, the least number $m>0$ with $2^m\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ q)$ is a divisor
of $2p$ because of $2^{2p}=(2^p)^2\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ q)$. If $m=2$, then
$q|2^2-1=3$, so $q=3$.

$m=p$ is impossible because of $2^p\equiv -1\ne 1 \ (\ mod\ q)$. $m=1$ is also impossible because of $2\ne 1\ (\ mod\ q\ )$.

Hence, $m=2p$. Because of $2^{q-1} \equiv 1\ (\ mod\ q)$ , we get $m=2p|q-1$.
This implies that $q$ must have the form $2kp+1$.